# How to solve the os error and load a model from hugging face in my jupyter. (Not local, Its on cluster)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, oserror

I am trying to load a pre-trained model from hugging face but everytime I am getting a os error.

[image]

I tried with

```
snapshot_download(repo_id = "google/flan-t5-base", cache_dir= "./huggingface_mirror")
```

but getting error as

```
ConnectionError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/models/google/flan-t5-base/revision/main (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x2af561da8190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))"), '(Request ID: 179fa5d0-e590-476f-87a1-77cbd1e5d5f3)')
```